# Harmon.ie add-in is causing Outlook 2016 on Windows 10 to crash

Tags: harmon.ie

We use Harmon.ie and recently it has started causing Outlook to crash. When we disable the Harmon.ie Add-In Outlook then runs without crashing.

I saw a previous post about a problem when running both Harmon.ie and ESET add-ins, but we don't have ESET so that's not the cause of our error.

Sean

Answer (score 0):

First make sure to download and install our latest 6.6 version from our web site.

-Make sure, the machine has been updated with latest Microsoft Office Updates and Windows updates. 
What Outlook version is in use?

-In order to rule out any plugin conflict would you please check whether any additional plugins are enabled in Outlook - if so, disable (temporarily) all other add-ins except harmon.ie To disable Outlook add-ins 
* Go under File -> Options -> Add-ins -> Manage COM Add-ins and click Go... 
Deselect all add-ins except harmon.ie and click OK. 
Restart Outlook - and go back under File -> Options -> Add-ins to verify that harmon.ie is the only add-in listed in the Active application add-ins section. 
Are you then reproducing the crash after disabling all the other plugins as suggested above?

If yes, I would like to get a full dump of the crash. If it is a crash a dump should be created.

Examine also Windows Event log (application section, Look at application error), it should have captured the crash and report the faulty module (attach the relevant information if you get it)

To get crash dump: 
-Stop Outlook 
-Extract inside a directory the procdump utility from Microsoft (SysInternals) at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1meqci0brf9hrl0/procdump.zip?dl=0 
-Start Outlook 
-Open a cmd command window, cd< directory_containing_procdump> 
-Office 32bits: procdump.exe -ma outlook -e harmonie.dmp 
-Office 64 bits: procdump.exe -64 -ma outlook -e harmonie.dmp I think you are running Office 64 bits. 
-Reproduce the crash 
-Zip and upload the generated harmonie.dmp for analysis.

----- Jean